# Strips/scratches on PlanetScope imagery

Tags: remote-sensing, imagery, atmospheric-correction, planet

I'm doing a project that evaluates the practicality of using remote sensing imagery in agricultural field management.

I noticed there are some scratches/strips on PlanetScope imagery for one of the paddocks. I'm not sure what causes this and more importantly, is it fixable and how? If not fixable, how can I avoid downloading bad quality imagery?

Product: 20180108_051245_0c79_3B

[image]

Comment: Could you check the link with the image? Nothing is showing up for me.

Comment: The image should turn up now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a single answer unfortunately. The satellites with the `0c` prefix are getting on in age and sometimes exhibit artifacts.

The UDM file signals which pixels have been detected as being anomalous and that can be a good way for users to know which pixels should be ignored.

But probably the best indicator before downloading anything is to check the `quality_category` attribute, which in this case is `test`. Look for `standard` for the best images.

Comment: Could it be a crossover like @Damini Jain suggested?

Comment: No, crossovers are two images of the same location by two different spacecraft within a short time window. However, what you have is an image from a single source. Whether there is a crossover or not has no effect on the image, its quality or any artifacts.

Answer (score -1):

Those strips are the satellite crossover. When two satellites image the same area on earth within a short window a crossover is witnessed.

Maybe the crossover adjustment method might help it represents orbital errors in terms of Fourier series and is more preferable to the conventional bias‐and‐tilt crossover adjustment method.

This link might help: https://medium.com/hipster-color-science/finding-satellite-crossovers-with-the-planet-api-73dcf2d23a49

https://www.planet.com/pulse/planets-framework-for-analysis-ready-data/